# BIOS-entry hangs, but normal startup is unaffected

Tags: bios, motherboard, freeze

I have a [Gigabyte B450M DS3H Motherboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FWVJSHC) with Lubuntu 20.04 on a [NVMe M.2 SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L6DKM8V) as the only OS, and a [PCIe Graphics Card](https://www.microcenter.com/product/606088/gigabyte-geforce-gtx-1650-overclocked-dual-fan-4gb-pcie-30-video-card) driving 3 displays.  Not using the onboard video at all.

When I let it start normally, everything's fine, but I've discovered that I can no longer access the BIOS settings.  When I use any of the "special keys" - DEL for settings, F12 for a one-time boot menu, etc. - it adds the list of keys to the bottom of the splash screen and hangs there.

[image]

My normal mouse and keyboard are on a USB hub, just for cable management, but it also does this with a directly-connected USB keyboard, and even a PS/2 keyboard that I keep around just to be handy for things like this.  (yes, I shut it down and removed the power before plugging it in or unplugging)

It also appears that the signal on the video cord is already cropped as shown.  Changing the monitor settings can distort it, but it always remains cropped at the same place.

I have not tried removing the graphics card yet, and using the onboard video to change the settings.  I'm really not looking forward to that.  Is there a known issue that absolutely requires that solution?  Or could it be something else that involves less re-configuring?

Comment: Have you tried holding down F12 *before* powering up and keeping it held during boot?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Prior experience on lots of other boards says that that's hardly ever detected, so I didn't think to try.  Doesn't hurt though, so I'll give it a shot tomorrow.  This board used to accept a single stroke at the right time, just like all the others I've known, but I don't remember if that was entirely before or some after I added the graphics card, as I didn't have it to start with.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Nope, holding it since before power-on, is not detected.  Normal startup all the way to the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I broke down and tried the graphics card.  Just unseated it from the PCIe socket, and moved one of my HDMI's to the onboard plug.  Worked perfectly, even with the keyboard through a USB hub.  And it also showed me that even a normal start to the desktop, with the graphics card installed, has a cropped BIOS splash screen compared to what it did this time.

I fixed the BIOS settings that I needed to, Save & Exit 'ed, waited for the splash again and then powered off before the OS could get confused, put the graphics card back in and the one HDMI back where it goes, and started back up.  Cropped BIOS splash as usual for that configuration, and went smoothly to the desktop without the OS knowing any different.

---

So that's the solution, but I'm a little put off by the method.  It used to "just work" before fancy-graphical BIOS'es.  (when they still used the ancient text-only mode with "graphics" primitives in the upper register of an otherwise-ASCII character set)  Seems to me that the manufacturers need to get together again and re-standardize it for the more modern look and feel.